# Face-API: There is no persisted faces of person in group

Tags: c#, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

i'm using ms github project :Facial-Recognition-Door
[Facial-Recognition-Door](https://github.com/ms-iot/Facial-Recognition-Door)

```
private async Task<bool> TrainingWhitelistAsync()
    {
        bool isSuccess = true;

        // Train whitelist after add all person
        Debug.WriteLine("Start training whitelist: " + WhitelistId);
        await _faceApiClient.TrainPersonGroupAsync(WhitelistId);

        TrainingStatus status;


        while(true)
        {
            status = await _faceApiClient.GetPersonGroupTrainingStatusAsync(WhitelistId);

            // wait for training to complete
            if (status.Status != Status.Running)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("GetPersonGroupTrainingStatusAsync stopped running:" + status.Message);
                if (status.Status == Status.Failed)
                {
                    isSuccess = false;
                }
                break;
            }

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Debug.WriteLine("GetPersonGroupTrainingStatusAsync still running:" + status.Message);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("GetPersonGroupTrainingStatusAsync end result: " + isSuccess);
        return isSuccess;
    }
```

every time when i run to 
status = await _faceApiClient.GetPersonGroupTrainingStatusAsync(WhitelistId);

it retruns me failed, and say GetPersonGroupTrainingStatusAsync stopped running:There is no persisted faces of person in group f473519e-452b-4a65-8e11-85ccdb02063e.

Is anything wrong or just i'm using a free key?
[my key screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE2B3.png)

can any one help me?

Comment: Is anythign wrong with ms _faceApiClient.TrainPersonGroupAsync(WhitelistId);

Comment: What does https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/persongroups/f473519e-452b-4a65-8e11-85ccdb02063e/persons?subscription-key={YOUR_FACE_KEY_WITHOUT_PARENTHESES} show?  You should be able to try it in any browser.